# Newline issue in string resources

Tags: android, string

So I have this funny issue with Android making double newline suddently in the middle of a text, I know I could use  to fix it but I'd like to know WHY!?

Here is the text I'm using:

```
<string name="description_13_1">I sommeren 1843 gjorde H.C. Andersen to ophold på Holsteenshus, den 8.-10. juli og igen den 18.-24. juli. I et brev til veninden Henriette Wulff beretter digteren om en fest på godset den 9.juli:
    \n
    \n”og nu i Løverdags rykkede vi ind paa Baronens andet Gods: Holsteenshuus, det tredie Pragt-Punkt i det fyenske Land; her er paa en Bakke, tæt ved Haven, et Panorama, som var man paa et Bjerg, milevidt seer man om sig, fra Als til Thorseng fra Odense Spiir til Assens Banker; Dagen efter vor Ankomst var her paa Holsteenshuus en Slags Folkefest; et Par Hundrede Mennesker fra Svendborg og Faaborg vare samlede for at see lidt ud i Verden; de havde en skrækkelig Mængde Mad med, hele Kurve fulde, det var en Nydelse!" (14. juli 1843)
    \n
    \nVed den lejlighed genså H.C. Andersen familien Voigt fra Faaborg, som han ikke havde set i 13 år. Brevet fortsætter:
    \n
    \n”Her traf jeg Deres Broder Peter, hvis Fartøi nu laae i Faaborg Fjord, han var i Selskab med Agent Voigts, jeg traf den hele Familie, de fleste af den havde jeg ikke seet i 13 Aar; ja saa længe er det siden jeg som ung Student fløi gjennem Landet med Hjertet fuldt af Sange…”
    \n
    \nI H.C. Andersens almanak fra 9. juli 1843 fremhæves særligt gensynet med et navngivent medlem af familien Voigt:
    \n
    \n”Folkefest ved Holsteenshuus traf sammen med Riborg, hendes Mand og Børn, (det er 13 Aar).”
    \n
    \nGensynet med Riborg Voigt – digterens efter eget udsagn første ulykkelige kærlighed – som han ikke havde set siden 1830 blev ikke nærmere kommenteret af H.C. Andersen. Men senere samme sommer skrev han eventyret ”Kjærestefolkene”, der kan læses som en afsked med hans ulykkelige kærlighed.
```

This should make 1 empty line between each text, but when it gets to the part: `\nVed den lejlighed`it starts to count the enter between the lines as a newline as well (but not the first time...) So what is going on here?

**Edit**:

So after adding 1 line at a time from the bottom and up I've figured out it only happens if the second paragraph is added, so it must be something in the second paragraph that causes it...

Comment: It works fine for me. As expected I got normal single separating line between every paragraph. No exception

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski "#¤=)/"% I still have it, even though I put it into a seperate String resource file, even though I test it on nexus 5 or nexus 6. Really odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following characters next to each other will mess with the string resources: `!"`

It will only display the `!` and all enter within the string resource will start to count as newline chars.